# WebRequest doomed to failure when starting from parallel thread

Tags: c#, .net

Consider following console application:

```
public static void Request(string url)
{
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
  {
    try
    {
      var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
      request.Timeout = 5000;
      request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Console.Out.WriteLine(e);
    }
    Console.Out.WriteLine(url);
  });
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Request("http://google.com?q=a");
  Request("http://google.com?q=b");
  Request("http://google.com?q=c");
  Request("http://google.com?q=d");
  Thread.Sleep(20000);

  Console.In.ReadLine();
}
```

Output will finish for 2 urls. But for the rest it will throw "The operation has timed out".
I know that there is a limit of parallel connections by default set to two. If I increase it to three then three will finish up.
I.E:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 3;
```

But my question is - why the rest of them doesn't finish up, but throws the operation has timed out instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the timeout includes the time the process was waiting in line for a connection to become available.

The timeout to represents *"I want to wait at most 5000ms after I call `GetResponse()` to get my response"* not *"I want to wait at most an additional 5000ms after `GetResponse()` has waited for a unlimited amount of time to get its turn in the queue."*

Now, you wonder, "but the query is so quick, it should not take more than 5000ms to complete!". The problem comes from the fact you did not close the response you got from GetResponse, [from the MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx#remarksToggle)

> You must call the Close method to close the stream and release the
>   connection. Failure to do so may cause your application to run out of
>   connections.

Calling `Dispose()` implicitly calls `Close()`, so if you update your code to dispose of your response then the used connection will become freed and one of the waiting requests will then be able to start up.

```
public static void Request(string url)
{
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
  {
    try
    {
      var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
      request.Timeout = 5000;
      using(var response = request.GetResponse())
      {
          Console.Out.WriteLine("Response - " + url);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Console.Out.WriteLine(e);
    }
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Method End - " + url);
  });
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Request("http://google.com?q=a");
  Request("http://google.com?q=b");
  Request("http://google.com?q=c");
  Request("http://google.com?q=d");
  Thread.Sleep(20000);

  Console.In.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I totally forgot Response is IDisposable :)